# Conseguir data de um website C#

Tags: c#, https

Estou a desenvolver um programa em C# que permite realizar um clique a uma determinada hora escolhida pelo utilizador. 
Por enquanto o programa faz o clique subtraindo a hora escolhida pelo utilizador com a hora local, mas descobri à pouco que através das ***Headers*** de um *website* dá para saber a hora exata do servidor, o que me facilitaria bastante pois o programa está a ser desenvolvido para funcionar com base no horário do mesmo.

Uso estas linhas de código ir buscar as ***Headers*** do website:

```
var myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.exemplo.com.pt/");
var response = myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

Para subtrair a hora inserida pelo utilizador e a hora local utilizo esta linha de código:

```
TimeSpan wait_time = objetivo.Subtract(DateTime.Now); //'objetivo' = hora inserida pelo utilizador
```

A minha pergunta é, como é que posso ir buscar apenas a data às ***Headers*** do website e depois subtrair à hora escolhida pelo utilizador?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O objeto `response` que utilizas é do tipo [`HttpResponse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httpresponse(v=vs.110).aspx). Ele possui uma propriedade chamada [`Headers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httpresponse.headers(v=vs.110).aspx), uma coleção de valores, através da qual deve ser possível ler os cabeçalhos da página.

Algo como:

```
string dataCabecalho = response.Headers.Get("Date");
```

Observe que o método `Get` dos cabeçalhos, para o cabeçalho `Date`, retorna um texto. Esse texto ainda deve ser transformado em data, algo como:

```
DateTime dataRealServidor;
DateTime.TryParse(dataCabecalho, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat, 
DateTimeStyles.None, out dataRealServidor);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Renan! Realmente funcionou retornando algo como `19-04-2017 15:30:35`. Existe alguma maneira de saber os Millisegundos também, ou a ***Header*** Date só devolve Horas, Minutos e Segundos?

Comment: Infelizmente, até onde sei, esse cabeçalho só vai até os segundos.